# How to make server inside vm have same ipaddress even though we change network

Tags: windows, networking, ip, vmware

I have windows server installed in a vmware with domain configured. I had configured a website in iis and kept network adapter as bridged in vmware and is able to access website outside vmware on my local computer. 
Problem is when i change my network on local server, we are not able to access website because earlier network range configured was different. For eg : first time it was in 192.168.Xx.XX series after changing network entire ipaddress  of local computer got changed to 10.02.XX.XX

Need to know how we can achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign another VM adapter to Local server and assign him static IP of your subnet or add a second IP to exiting network Adapter. After adding static IP of your subnet to local server, you can assign this IP to you IIS site and can access it from all  of your network.

You can also configure NAT/bridge connection again on your server Vmware network adapter as you did earlier (what is the issue?).

If you dont want to assign ip of your local network to server vm, you can also assign second ip address to your host machine network adapter( If clients are not many).

Answer (score 0):

you should also adjust the website's or VM's ip matching your network segment.
so if your network subnet is already 10.x.x.x change your websites ip to 10.x.x.x . or if you dont want to change your website's ip then you should configure routing or NAT

Comment: Any ref article that would be helpful to achieve this.